# logging how many times a command has been used biased on user id [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to log how many times a command has been used on a particular user and then write it to a file to be added to every time the command is triggered.

Here's the command that i am trying to do this for

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def boop(ctx):
    mentions = ctx.message.mentions
    for user in mentions:
        await client.say("{} has been Boop'ed!".format(user))
```

I'm trying to write a number, along with the `userid` to a json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to maintain a dictionary mapping users to the number of times they have been mentioned.  Then you can just use [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) to send that to a file.  You should note that this doesn't scale very well.  If you see yourself updating this file constantly, you should consider switching to an asynchronous database (Especially because file writes are a blocking operation).

```
import json
from collections import Counter

boop_dict = Counter()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def boop(ctx, *users: discord.User):
    for user in users:
        await client.say("{} has been Boop'ed!".format(user))
        boop_dict[user.id] += 1
    with open('boop_file.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(boop_dict, f)
```